# JavaScript: Check when button was un-pressed without using onkeyup

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I have a task:

1. Run animation on button click
2. Run animation just once on holding a button
3. Use just "onKeyDown" the only dom event that device supports

Here you can see the example how I did this:

```
let timer = null;
let isPressed = false;

const runAnimation = () => {
    div.classList.remove('run-animation');
    void div.offsetWidth;
    div.classList.add('run-animation');
}

const fillDiv = () => {
  if (!isPressed) {
    isPressed = true;
    runAnimation();
  }

  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    isPressed = false;
  }, 50);
};

document.onkeydown = function() {
  fillDiv();
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrbObO)

But the problem here, that when you hold button, the animation plays twice

Is there some solution how to avoid second firing of run animation?

Comment: Your animation takes longer to run than your timeout.... maybe try a different approach. I change the timeout to 1501 to test and it fired only once, as expected.

Comment: you can use keyup event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087959/prevent-javascript-keydown-event-from-being-handled-multiple-times-while-held-do

Comment: @Stuart Yes, I can change the timeout, but appropriate one is "550ms", so it doesn't work for me because I need to fire animation second time if you re-click the button

Comment: @VladuIonut How I said, I cannot use it. The device doesn't support "onKeyUp"

Comment: how about [onanimationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)?

Comment: @AndrewBone Imagine that you will click button 3 times in a row. Not all the time animation will be done and sometime you will need to re-run it. So I'm not sure how "onAnimationed" can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is a way to look for if the key is being held down. The [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown#Properties) event object contains a property called repeat.

> true if a key has been depressed long enough to trigger key repetition; otherwise, false.

We can check this. If it's true we can just return without doing anything otherwise we can start the `fillDiv` function.

I've stipped out all the bits that are no longer needed like `isPressed` and `timer`

To make it work I had to pass `e` as an argument in your event listener, I used `e` to represent `event`.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('test');

const runAnimation = () => {
  div.classList.remove('run-animation');
  void div.offsetWidth;
  div.classList.add('run-animation');
}

const fillDiv = () => {
  runAnimation();
};

document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.repeat) return;
  fillDiv();
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes runAnimation {
  from {
    background-color: green;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.run-animation {
  -webkit-animation: runAnimation 1.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#test {
  padding: 10px 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  font-size: 26pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="center">
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)

```js
const div = document.getElementById('test');
let timer = null;
let isPressed = false;
let isRunning = false

const runAnimation = () => {
    isRunning = true;
    div.classList.remove('run-animation');
    void div.offsetWidth;
    div.classList.add('run-animation');
}

const fillDiv = () => {
   if (!isPressed) runAnimation();  
};

document.onkeydown = function() {
  if (!isRunning) fillDiv();
    isPressed = true;
}
document.onkeyup = function() {
  isPressed = false;
}

 div.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
   console.log("animationend") 
   isRunning = false;
 });
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes runAnimation {
   from { background-color: green; }
     to { background-color: white; }
}

.run-animation {
  -webkit-animation: runAnimation 1.5s ease;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#test {
  padding: 10px 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  font-size: 26pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="center">
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you click 3 - 5 times button, the animation runs with some delay or doesn't run at all. Also, when you click and hold button, animation fires just when you release button, not when you just clicked it.

But for me, I need to show that button was clicked. Basically, animation should run just one user clicked the button. If user hold button, then I just run when he has clicked, and all other time it's on hold

Comment: Also with this approach, animation fires in a cycle when you hold a button

Comment: [How it looks like if I would have an "onKeyUp"](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrbObO?editors=1010)

Comment: I've updated the code maybe you don't need the animation running logic

Comment: Guys I cannot use OnKeyUp! A device doesn't support it, so in JS I don't know about this event!

Comment: @DenisEfremov what device is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot name it. It's a device with the custom Android and remote which fires "onKeyDown" when user interacts with the device

Comment: @DenisEfremov testing this example in a desktop device shows none of the problems you are describing for me - so that would make me question first of all, does your mysterious device support animationend to begin with? Asking for solutions here that have to work under such restrictions, that we probably don’t even know the half of yet, seems rather not a good fit for this site IMHO. (Or you would have at least to provide us with a list of what it _does_ support first.)

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure that I can understand you.
1. I have said that you can use just "onkeydown" but in the example above "onkeyup" is used
2. All examples I have tested on PC and if it would work as I asked on PC it would work on the device. The device from the key event handle just onkeydown, that's all. All other events should triggers as expected (without mouseclicks because it doesn't have mouse)