# How to avoid holding key triggering multiple events (JS)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to create this event to navigate through the website with arrow keys.
The problem that I'm facing is that if someone holds one of the keys, the function (in this case `console.log`) will trigger repeatedly which may cause some undesirable behaviour with complex functions.

I want `console.log` to be triggered only once for each keydown.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            console.log('left');
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            console.log('right');
            break;
    }
});
```

I ended up using this:

```
let allowKey = true;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            if (allowKey) {
                console.log('Left');
                allowKey = false;
            }
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            if (allowKey) {
                console.log('Right');
                allowKey = false;
            }
            break;
    }
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            allowKey = true;
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            allowKey = true;
            break;
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check for [`!e.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent JavaScript keydown event from being handled multiple times while held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087959/prevent-javascript-keydown-event-from-being-handled-multiple-times-while-held-do)

Comment: e.repeat doesn't work for me, it looks like the OS occasionally will send multiple 'keydown' signals when holding a key.

Comment: Which OS does this?

Comment: Windows, I tested it again. And is a very frequent behaviour on Chrome, on Firefox it happen more rarely.
So logging the value of 'e.repeat' holding a key, listening to the event 'keydown', it should log once 'false' and then multiple 'true' until you release the key. The abnormal behaviour is that you can see, sometimes only, 2 'false' logged and then the multiple 'true' in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a variable that checks if the key went up. Like this:

```js
var isKeyDown = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (!isKeyDown) {
      isKeyDown = true;
    } else {
      return
    }
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            console.log('left');
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            console.log('right');
            break;
    }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  isKeyDown = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best solution. I wrote a slightly different code inspired by this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the event.repeat to check if the key is already been pressed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            
            if (e.repeat) return;

              //your code 
            switch (e.key) {
              
                case 'ArrowLeft':
                    console.log('left');
                    break;
                case 'ArrowRight':
                    console.log('right');
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this with 'keydown' but unfortunately, this doesn't work as intended, it looks like the OS occasionally will send multiple 'keydown' signals when holding a key.
* 'keyup' is not very responsive so I won't consider it.

Comment: `repeat` doesn’t make sense with `keyup`. Use `keydown` instead.

Comment: yes sorry, i mistyped it should have been keydown

Answer (score -1):

change 'keydown' to 'keyup'. that will only run when the key is released, so its foolproof. Like so:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            switch (e.key) {
                case 'ArrowLeft':
                    console.log('left');
                    break;
                case 'ArrowRight':
                    console.log('right');
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but to be clear. The console log does not happen whenever a user presses down a button. Only when they release the key again. This could be annoying timing wise..

Comment: 'keyup' is not very responsive so I won't consider it.