# How to track the time of the pressed button? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I need your help. With the help of the following code, I am trying to detect the time that the `Delete` key was pressed. My code doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't work quite right. For example, if I press the key for 3 seconds, it shows a completely different time than it should. Tell me what I am doing wrong, what is my mistake? Thank you very much?)

```
var startTime;

document.body.onkeydown = function() {
   const key = event.key;
   if (key === 'Delete') {
      console.log('key down');
      startTime = +new Date();
   }
}

document.body.onkeyup = function() {
   const key = event.key;
   if (key === 'Delete') {
     console.log('key up')
     var endTime = +new Date();
     var time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
     if (time > 3) {
        console.log('cool')
     }
    console.log(time + ' sec');
   }
}
```

Comment: `shows a completely different time`...give an example: what time did you expect? What time did you actually get?

Comment: `if (event.repeat) return;` in `onkeydown`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent JavaScript keydown event from being handled multiple times while held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087959/prevent-javascript-keydown-event-from-being-handled-multiple-times-while-held-do)

Comment: use this condition in both function keydown and keyup `key === 'Delete' || key === 'Backspace'`

Comment: @ADyson I had i time less than 1 second every time. Maybe it was i time pressing button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore multiple repetitions using a little flag you set up.

```js
var startTime;
var delete_down = false;

document.body.onkeydown = function(ev) {
  const key = event.key;
  if (key === 'Delete') {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (delete_down) {
      return
    }
    delete_down = true;
    console.log('key down');

    startTime = +new Date();
  }
}

document.body.onkeyup = function() {
  const key = event.key;
  if (key === 'Delete') {
    console.log('key up')
    delete_down = false;
    var endTime = +new Date();
    var time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    if (time > 3) {
      console.log('cool')
    }
    console.log(time + ' sec');
  }
}
```

```html
click me then hit [Del]
```

Comment: Thank you)) It works fine, what i needed? Where was my mistake?

Comment: As been suggested in the comments, the event is re-triggered many times while key is down. So solution was to ignore all of them after the first one.

Comment: Only one more question, how to clear this pressed time?

Comment: If you want to remove the events then `document.body.onkeydown=null`. Note that I `ev.preventDefault();` If [Del] was pressed, maybe that wasn't your intention.

Comment: My question is that I am using this code in Angular Typescript. And the time I have, when it is pressed every time, is added

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: The following behavior is desired: I press the key and wait 3 seconds. When I press again, the time starts from zero and wait 3 seconds again. For some reason, when I click again, my time adds up

If comments are blocked, please write to dcheyrnak10@gmail.com

Comment: I want to see the time the button was pressed, every time I press it

Comment: I'm sorry don't understand. But take my code as example it's understandable. Try to build upon it, or [edit] your question so it would be more clear.